# Is it possible to combine a dictionary of lists together into one list?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary like so:

```
my_list = {
    "foo": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "bar": ["d", "e", "f"]
}
```

How could I combine all lists in this dictionary into one large list in one line of code (meaning there would not be a temporary variable)? I came up with the following solution, however it is not very elegant:

```
def combine_list_dictionary():
    temp = []
    for (key, value_list) in my_list:
        temp += value_list
    return temp

combine_list_dictionary()  # ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

I don't mind that the keys are lost in the process.

Comment: Please clarify - you have a dictionary named `my_list` and describe the output you want, clearly a list, as a dictionary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe he did on the last line of his coding

Comment: @jonrsharpe The last line of my example contains a comment with what the output should be

Comment: @Paradoxis but why is the dictionary called `my_list`? Why do you refer to the output, **a list**, as *"one large dictionary"*? `for (key, value_list) in my_list:` won't work on a dictionary, you're missing a call to `items`, so **what is the actual situation?** `sum(my_list.values(), [])` will do what you want, if you actually have a dictionary where all values are lists.

Comment: I have edited for consistency, but note that your current code **does not work** with your claimed inputs. Also `my_list` is an unwise name for not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use `sum` to join lists.  There is a long discussion on the python ideas mailing list around why that is a bad idea (will get link later).

`itertools.chain` is a good solution, or if you rather go functional then

```
>>> my_list = {
...     "foo": ["a", "b", "c"],
...     "bar": ["d", "e", "f"]
... }
>>> import operator as op
>>> reduce(op.concat, my_list.values())
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>>
```

Here is a performance comparison between `chain` and `reduce` for both small and large dictionaries.

```
>>> import random
>>> dict_of_lists = {k: range(random.randint(0, k)) for k in range(0, random.randint(0, 9))}
>>> %timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list.values()))
The slowest run took 12.72 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 995 ns per loop
>>> %timeit reduce(op.concat, my_list.values())
The slowest run took 19.77 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 467 ns per loop
```

`reduce` is about twice as fast as `itertools`.  That is true for larger structures.

```
>>> dict_of_lists = {k: range(random.randint(0, k)) for k in range(0, random.randint(0, 9999))}
>>> %timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list.values()))
The slowest run took 6.47 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1 µs per loop
>>> %timeit reduce(op.concat, my_list.values())
The slowest run took 13.68 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 425 ns per loop
```

Comment: The problem with `sum` is that a new list is created for each step, which is potentially inefficient. That may not be relevant if the lists and dictionary aren't very large.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools`.

```
import itertools
combined_results = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list.values()))
```

Comment: Yes, but why would you? You don't get much benefit from `itertools` if you immediately consume the iterator into a list!

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
result = sorted(sum(my_list.values(), []))
```

Remove `sorted` if your result does not need to be *sorted*